# Why does sometimes Volley's StringRequest give me an empty response?

Tags: android, multithreading, network-programming, httpurlconnection, android-volley

I'm using Google's network library Volley to perform a set of operations. In particular, I'm relying on `StringRequest` in order to fetch the HTML of some protected pages. In order to perform the (authenticated) request, I always add to the request a set of cookies.

The problem is that, without any apparent reason, Volley *sometimes* gives me an empty source code! (and this WITHOUT a 204 status code: It's a pure 200).

```
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    // HERE: response.data sometimes has size 0!
    // on the other hand, response.statusCode is 200.
    // [...]
}
```

I am completely sure that this is not a problem of the remote server (when I navigate the very same page, with the same cookies, using a web browser, everything is fine). I'm also having a lot of issues regarding `TimeoutError` (don't know whether it's something relevant or not).

I'm REALLY tempted to switch to something written ad hoc in order to settle things once and for all, but the multithreading features that Volley implements out of the box are still a huge factor that is restraining me.

Comment: Have you tried running an HTTP proxy like Charles or Fiddler2 to ensure that you're getting a proper response body?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the TimeoutError, did you setting the retry policy? For example, with

```
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```